# why does Listview + Selector crash from xml file

Tags: xml, listview, crash, selector

I have a list view, that I want the background to change color when it clicked (Touched) by the user.

Each listItem is as fallows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/row_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/row_background">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/RowImg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight = "1" 
            android:background="#ffffff" 
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:maxHeight="48dp"    />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/RowText1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"                   
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000080"
                android:background="#ffffff" 
                android:layout_weight = "2"  />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Inside the drawable I have the fallowing file (row_background.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:background="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:background="@color/green" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:background="@color/green" />
    <item android:background="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

And then I have the color file inside the values folder (color.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <color name="green">#808080</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

When I try to run with the colors the selector it crashes. If I run with only white background, without calling the selector everything works ok.

Can somebody tell me what is wrong?

Thanks, 
Adrian.

Answer (score 1):

Codes for the colors in the XML are wrong... you need to add '#FF' before the code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <resources>
    <color name="green">#FF808080</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    </resources>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the solution?